# avoid Value property for nullable value types?

Tags: c#, struct, pattern-matching, nullable, c#-8.0

If I have a nullable value type I always have to use its Value property, even after I checked it for null. Is there a consise way around it?

```
public void Foo(SomeStruct? s)
{
    if (s != null)
    {
        DoIt(s.Value.x + s.Value.y + s.Value.z);
    }
}
```

The obvious way would be to define a new variable which makes the code longer for each variable it affects and which I find makes the code harder to read:

```
    if (s != null)
    {
        var sv = s.Value;
        DoIt(sv.x + sv.y + sv.z);
    }
```

One other thing that came to my mind is pattern matching, but this has the drawback of a runtime typecheck:

```
    if (s is SomeStruct sv)
    {
        DoIt(sv.x + sv.y + sv.z);
    }
```

Am I overlooking something (besides the fact that I maybe should avoid null variables in the first place)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If C# 8 is available to you - you can use property pattern which actually is turned into `HasValue` check:

```
    if(s is {} sv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sv);
    }
```

Will be turned by compiler into something like this ([sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8BmAAiJoGEaBvCm9u2/FGgWQAoAyhAC2MQQBcoAVzASA/DQDOAShZsOmgJYAzfkppaDzAL7KAbio2b2rcjYd1iATn2WA3NZsmvP+x2plKVkJGmExSRk5Uwo/IA=)):

```
    int num;
    if (s.HasValue)
    {
        valueOrDefault = s.GetValueOrDefault();
        num = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        num = 0;
    }
    if (num != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(valueOrDefault);
    }
```

Comment: You might make a note of the version restrictions on the code you are showing.  A lot of us are using older versions of the compiler.  It's easy to upgrade Visual Studio, it take longer to get the company build system upgraded.

Comment: Although the generated code looks inefficient at first glance, I checked that in release configuration it indeed generates the same code that I would get when I'd done a normal null-check.

Comment: The syntax is somewhat ugly and unintuitive..but it is nevertheless exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

**`if (s is SomeStruct sv)` does *not* result in a runtime type-check.** It's just a straight `HasValue` check

See [this on Sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4fsJToFkAFAEo2HLhOwA7DAH46CALwBWANziJnbADM6ghHWwBnQzIUA3YRs3tKm+xYB0AFQgBlDFGkBzEersOAL7WEtbBlIFAA===) for instance:

```cs
int? x=5;
if (x is int xv)
{
    xv.ToString();
}
```

This compiles down to the equivalent of:

```cs
int? x=5;
int xv;
if (x.HasValue)
{
    xv = x.GetValueOrDefault();
    xv.ToString();
}
```

Note that `GetValueOrDefault` is fully optimized and does not check the `bool HasValue` flag.

The actual IL is as follows

```
        IL_0000: ldloca.s 0
        IL_0002: ldc.i4.5
        IL_0003: call instance void valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::.ctor(!0)
        IL_0008: ldloca.s 0
        IL_000a: call instance bool valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
        IL_000f: brfalse.s IL_0021

        IL_0011: ldloca.s 0
        IL_0013: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
        IL_0018: stloc.1
        IL_0019: ldloca.s 1
        IL_001b: call instance string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32::ToString()
        IL_0020: pop
```

Comment: ok right, for value types, no typecheck will be needed.